# How to register same interface multiple times in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to register 2 interfaces implemented by the same class in different ways. My current implementation is like the one shown below

`IInterface1 : ServiceClass`

`IInterface2 : ServiceClass`, where IInterface2 inherits from IInterface1

Then in my Startup.cs, I register them as

`services.AddScoped<IInterface1>(x => {return ServiceClass(ConnectionString1)})`
`services.AddScoped<IInterface2>(x => {return ServiceClass(ConnectionString2)})`

The problem is I'm creating a library, so having a redundant interface is not something I would like. Ideally, I would like to remove IInterface2 from the library.
Is there any way I can register the same interface with different parameters?

I've looked at all the related questions asked here but all the requirements were different, since most of them had different classes implementing them.

Comment: How would you like to differentiate the 2 implementations if they have the same interface?

Comment: You cannot do that. DI wouldn't know which one of the two to inject. There surely is a better solution to your problem (X Y problem).

Comment: Your DI has a problem: You know a John Smith and a John Doe but you introduce both as just "John" to your DI. Now you tell your DI "I need John, can you get him for me?" - Do you mean John Doe or John Smith?

Answer (score 0):

As I know build-in DI cannot do that. To workaround it, you can use [`Autofac`](https://autofac.org/) for example, which allows such scenarios. In asp .net core you have to [setup Autofac as DI container](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting). Next, you can register multiple implementations of the same interface. To resolve those use `IEnumerable<T>`.

One more thing - you don't have to think about DI nor enforce DI. DI mechanism is something outside of your interests.